# Can not add local property to LS screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Has anybody experienced proplem with adding local property to the lightswitch screen. When I open Add Local Property dialog my dropdown list with local property types is empty. Is there any solution?

Comment: Is Microsoft LightSwitch Extensions checked? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/49156195-9b3b-469e-819a-c11cbbfa5273/

Comment: What version of LS are you using? I remember hearing about this back in the V1 Beta 2 timeframe, but I don't think I've heard of it since LS RTM'd.